# How to implement VDI solution using OpenStack

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack, vdi

I'm new in the domain of cloud. And for my internship, i'm working on the implementation of an open source **VDI (Virutal Desktop Infrastructure)** solution.
After a few days googling VDI and cloud infrastructure, I found that OpenStack can help with it. I started installing and configuring services.

Now I'm looking for how to implement something like what is offered by *citrix or Vmware*.
In terms of use case, we have about 30 developpers and they are in remote work. We want to centralize data and software in one or more virtual or not desktops. In that way any of them will be able to log in their desktop and work in their own session and access shared files, etc... So that they would be able to log in their account using any device that support the login client.

Is there any way to do that with openstack ? If yes thank for advice and recommandation about it.
If no, which opensource or free solution will be suitable ?

Any advice will be very helpful.
Thank you so much

Comment: I think this question is too broad for us to answer. A simple search will show you some examples of how people have implemented VDI solutions on top of openstack; take a look at some existing solutions and see if that points you in a useful direction.

Comment: Thank you @larsks I've searched on google for VDI solution with openstack but the only relevant ressource was The video made by the team from openstack.
Unfortunately there are not sufficient detail to reproduce what they did. But now i've dive into the documentation and I think everything is going well.